# looping through an array without loading data set each time

Tags: arrays, perl

In the below code I am trying to search for each time one of the URL's in my array is accessed. This script works... however there is unncessary overhead since I am loading up
the "external.access_logs" for every iteration in my for loop.

also I would like to pull out the IP address from the log line on each URL match, below is an example log line, any guidance would be appreciated.

```
2014-08-28      16:19:36        GET    /login/do.jsp 200     -       "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"     -       727e13230b5dadbab1c0b6eda77dcf613ba5120e80dbaff753ff8e14e3d36aae501e3a004aeba73e238a50e36bc3c5922491f01cd433de30663ddeb2fb09d023c742a9e5e16f5b4eb08b213d"  -       -       -       "45.25.25.64"
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $date1 = `date -d "-1 day" +"%y-%m-%d"`;
chomp $date1;

my @array = ( "/login/do.jsp", "/logout/do.jsp", "/query/do.jsp" );

print "# of times resource was used, resource URL\n";

for (@array) {
    chomp $_;
    my $cmd = `cat /weblogs/daily_summaries/$date1/external.access_logs |awk {'print   \$4'} |grep -i "$_" |wc -l`;
    chomp $cmd;
    print "$cmd,$_\n";
}
print "Complete!\n";
```

Comment: There's no need to call `date`, `cat`, or `awk` inside a Perl script. You can do all of those things in pure Perl and should avoid invoking a shell unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the log file once to build your counts:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $date1 = `date -d "-1 day" +"%y-%m-%d"`;
chomp $date1;

my %count;

open my $fh, '<', "/weblogs/daily_summaries/$date1/external.access_logs";
while (<>) {
    my $file = (split)[3] // next;
    $count{$file}++;
}

my @array = ( "/login/do.jsp", "/logout/do.jsp", "/query/do.jsp" );

print "# of times resource was used, resource URL\n";

for (@array) {
    print "$count{$_},$_\n";
}
print "Complete!\n";
```

Comment: thanks for the input miller, when I try to run the code, i get an error on the split command i think.. "Use of uninitialized value $file in hash element at line 14"

Comment: Then one of your data lines does not contain a 4th element.  One easy way to fix that is to add a shortcut to skip to the next line if that value is undefined.  I've edited the script to do that.